# GateIn 3.2 ignores actionURL parameters

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat7, gatein

I'm using `GateIn 3.2.0.FINAL` with `Tomcat 7` (`GateIn-3.2.0.Final-tomcat7.zip`). It looks like the parameters in the `actionURL` are ignored.

My controller looks like this:

```
@ActionMapping("search")
public void search(ActionRequest request) {
    LOG.info("doing search");
}

@ActionMapping("save")
public void save(ActionRequest request) {
    LOG.info("doing save");
}
```

My JSP looks like this:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="saveURL">
    <portlet:param name="javax.portlet.action" value="save"/>
</portlet:actionURL>

<form:form id="${ns}-save" action="${saveURL}" modelAttribute="createModel">
    <!-- omitted some html -->
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

When I press the submit button, the POST should include a `javax.portlet.action=save`, but it doesn't. No parameter named `javax.portlet.action` is included, and an exception is thrown because no matching `@ActionMapping` method can be found.

The URL generated for the `form` tag in the HTML looks like this:

```
/portal/classic/home/Permissions?navigationalstate=<gibberish>&amp;portal:componentId=<an UUID>&amp;interactionstate=<gibberish>&amp;portal:type=action&amp;portal:isSecure=false
```

If I manually edit the URL with firebug and add `&javax.portlet.action=save` to it, it works like a charm and it finds the `save()` method in the controller.

Now, if I deploy the exact same `war` in `jBoss Portal 2.7.2`, `&javax.portlet.action=save` is included in the URL. The same is true for `GateIn 3.1.0.FINAL` with `Tomcat 6`.

**PS**

I've also tried with another parameter key:

```
@ActionMapping({params = "myparam=save"})
public void save(ActionRequest request) {
    LOG.info("doing save");
}
```

...and:

```
<portlet:actionURL var="saveURL">
    <portlet:param name="myparam" value="save"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

...with the same results. Works find in `GateIn 3.1` and `jBoss Portal 2.7.2`, but not `GateIn 3.2`.

It also does not work with `GateIn 3.2.0.FINAL` with `Tomcat 6`.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that doing this works, but I'd prefer not to use it:

```
<form:form id="${ns}-save" action="${saveURL}&javax.portlet.action=save" modelAttribute="createModel">
   <!-- omitted -->
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ActionMapping({params = "action=save"})
public void save(ActionRequest request) { 
    LOG.info("doing save"); 
}
```

and

```
<portlet:actionURL var="saveURL" escapeXml="false">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="save"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

action is default param name and you must do other changes to use your own.

Comment: It's the same thing as ActionMapping("save") and portlet:param name="javax.portlet.action". Already tried. See the post script in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `escapeXML="false"` on actionURL.

Comment: Hey Oscar Did u get the solution of this problem actually i am also facing kind of same problem